# How to insert data into 3 different tables from an XML file

Tags: xml, delphi, import, delphi-2010

In an Access database I have 3 tables:Table,Table2 and Table3. Table1 is master for Table2 and Table2 is master for Table3. So whenever I scroll Table1 I get both Table2 and Table3 scrolled at the accordingly. I'm using Delphi 2010 for application side. I can export data from the join of the three tables to an XML file. And then I have to import the data to another database which has got the same structure as the source database. How can I accomplish this? Is there a good XML parser for Delphi that I can use? Or is there one already built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XML Data Binding Wizard](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Using_the_XML_Data_Binding_Wizard) to generate classes representing data from XML. Then you can use these classes to insert data into datasets.